# how to reseed qrand() in Qt?

Tags: qt, seed

I use this the generate random string in Qt:

```
GenerateRandomString()
{
const QString possibleCharacters("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
const int randomStringLength = 5; // assuming you want random strings of 5 characters

QString randomString;
for(int i=0; i<randomStringLength; ++i)
{
   int index = qrand() % possibleCharacters.length();
   QChar nextChar = possibleCharacters.at(index);
   randomString.append(nextChar);
}
return randomString;
}
```

however the strings it generates repeat every time I start the debug (or run the program). It seems like qrand() is seeded the same every time. How can I properly reseed qrand() so that it is more random? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution... I add this to the constructor so the program is seeded differently every time. It works for my purpose.

```
QDateTime cd = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
qsrand(cd.toTime_t());
```

Comment: Please note toTime_t() is deprecated as of Qt5.8. See my answer for alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Yep's answer, since `QDateTime::toTime_t()` is deprecated since `Qt5.8`, the following will work just as well:

```
qsrand(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()%UINT_MAX);
```